CMake Build Errors with Firebase Integration in Flutter Project
CMake Error at flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/firebase_core/windows/CMakeLists.txt:119 (add_subdirectory):
The source directory
D:/infinity_pms_client/build/windows/x64/extracted/firebase_cpp_sdk_windows

does not contain a CMakeLists.txt file.
CMake Error at flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/firebase_core/windows/CMakeLists.txt:125 (get_target_property):
get_target_property() called with non-existent target "firebase_app".
CMake Error at flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/firebase_core/windows/CMakeLists.txt:126 (string):
string sub-command REPLACE requires at least four arguments.
CMake Error at flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/firebase_core/windows/CMakeLists.txt:127 (set_target_properties):
set_target_properties Can not find target to add properties to:
firebase_app
CMake Error at flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/firebase_core/windows/CMakeLists.txt:125 (get_target_property):
get_target_property() called with non-existent target "firebase_auth".
CMake Error at flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/firebase_core/windows/CMakeLists.txt:126 (string):
string sub-command REPLACE requires at least four arguments.
CMake Error at flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/firebase_core/windows/CMakeLists.txt:127 (set_target_properties):
set_target_properties Can not find target to add properties to:
firebase_auth
CMake Error at flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/firebase_core/windows/CMakeLists.txt:125 (get_target_property):
get_target_property() called with non-existent target "firebase_storage".
CMake Error at flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/firebase_core/windows/CMakeLists.txt:126 (string):
string sub-command REPLACE requires at least four arguments.
CMake Error at flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/firebase_core/windows/CMakeLists.txt:127 (set_target_properties):
set_target_properties Can not find target to add properties to:
firebase_storage
does not contain a CMakeLists.txt file.
CMake Error at flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/firebase_core/windows/CMakeLists.txt:125 (get_target_property): get_target_property() called with non-existent target "firebase_app".
CMake Error at flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/firebase_core/windows/CMakeLists.txt:126 (string): string sub-command REPLACE requires at least four arguments.
CMake Error at flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/firebase_core/windows/CMakeLists.txt:127 (set_target_properties): set_target_properties Can not find target to add properties to: firebase_app
CMake Error at flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/firebase_core/windows/CMakeLists.txt:125 (get_target_property): get_target_property() called with non-existent target "firebase_auth".
CMake Error at flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/firebase_core/windows/CMakeLists.txt:126 (string): string sub-command REPLACE requires at least four arguments.
CMake Error at flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/firebase_core/windows/CMakeLists.txt:127 (set_target_properties): set_target_properties Can not find target to add properties to: firebase_auth
CMake Error at flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/firebase_core/windows/CMakeLists.txt:125 (get_target_property): get_target_property() called with non-existent target "firebase_storage".
CMake Error at flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/firebase_core/windows/CMakeLists.txt:126 (string): string sub-command REPLACE requires at least four arguments.
CMake Error at flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/firebase_core/windows/CMakeLists.txt:127 (set_target_properties): set_target_properties Can not find target to add properties to: firebase_storage StepsSteps to Reproduce:
Set up the Flutter project with Firebase dependencies in pubspec.yamlpubspec.yaml. Run flutter build windows to compile the project. Observe the build errors related to CMake and Firebase.
Expected Result: The
The project should build successfully without errors related to missing CMake files or non-existent Firebase targets.
Has anyone else encountered similar CMake errors when integrating Firebase? What steps can be taken to resolve these missing files and target issues in the CMake configuration? Are there specific versions of Firebase or Flutter that are known to work without these build issues? Thank you!
